# Сетка QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

У [`QTreeView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html) него нет метода аналогичного [`QTableView::setShowGrid`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#showGrid-prop). И как теперь отобразить сетку?

Comment: Не помню что б у TreeView была сетка... корень, линии, наличие/отсутствие кнопок/иконок/переключателей. Но сетка....

Comment: Может QListView?

Comment: @nick_n_a, именно `QTreeView`. В модели можно сделать много строк  и колонок. А вот разлинеить это все в представлении никак

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно с помощью делегата.

```
    void GridLineDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
  QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);

  if (index.isValid())
  {
    painter->setPen(Qt::SolidLine);
    painter->setPen(QColor(Qt::lightGray));

    painter->drawLine(QLine(option.rect.bottomLeft(), option.rect.bottomRight()));
    painter->drawLine(QLine(option.rect.topRight(), option.rect.bottomRight()));
  }
}
```

А затем

```
ui->treeView->setItemDelegate(new GridLineDelegate(ui->treeView));
```

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое решение, которое мне удалось найти, это использование стилей:

```
QTreeView *view = new QTreeView(this);
view->setStyleSheet("*::item{"
                    "    border-top-width: 0px;"
                    "    border-right-width: 1px;"
                    "    border-bottom-width: 1px;"
                    "    border-left-width: 0px;"
                    "    border-style: solid;"
                    "    border-color: silver;"
                    "}"
                    "*::item:selected{"
                    "    background: palette(Highlight);"
                    "}");
```

По какой-то причине выделенные ячейки перестали подсвечиваться. Поэтому пришлось дополнительно описать `*::item:selected`.

Comment: а почему не this->setStyleSheet(...) ?

Comment: @AndrioSkur, тогда я применю этот стиль ко всему родительскому виджету. А мне надо только к конкретному представлению